# "Walking makes him feel good." - Why don't we use "makes him feels good"?

Tags: verbs, infinitives, verb-agreement

I'm confused on why the following is correct.

> Walking makes him feel good.

Since "him" is the third person (he/she/it). Shouldn't it be:

> Walking makes him feels good.

This sounds wrong, but how can I explain?  Does the verb agreement not play when it is regarding the object of the subject?

Comment: *him* is the object, not the subject of the sentence. That's *walking*, and the verb *makes* agrees with this already.

Comment: "Feel good" is a subordinate bare infinitival clause, so "feel" is an infinitive verb-form; it's untensed, so there is **no** verb agreement.

Comment: Causative-make takes a bare-infinitival complement.

Answer (score 2):

The verb would be "feels" if the subject of the sentence were "he;" however, the form "him" is never the subject, and in this case is the object of make.  That's the short answer.

What feel exactly is in this sentence is complicated, and I'm not sure I understand it.  But here's my guess: "feel" is an auxiliary infinitive used with "make."  Unlike most infinitives, it is not expressed with the word "to" in front of it.  I'm not sure why, but it is an infinitive.  Consider this sentence with "cause" instead of "make."

> Walking causes him **to feel** good.

In this case feel is also an infinitive, expressed normally.

Comment: The [Verb Patterns article in the Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/verb-patterns-verb-infinitive-or-verb-ing#verb-patterns-verb-infinitive-or-verb-ing__4) might help explain. "Let and make are followed by an infinitive without to in active voice sentences. They always have an object ... before the infinitive."